# The order of $bab^{-1}$ is equal to the order of $a$ for any $a,b \in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group. Prove that the order of $bab^{-1}$ is equal to the order of $a$, $\forall a,b \in G$

Comment: Conjugation is an automorphism :D

Comment: Use the definition?

Comment: Please show your working so far :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Order of conjugate of an element given the order of this element](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633757/order-of-conjugate-of-an-element-given-the-order-of-this-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Key Idea** $\ $ Isomorphisms  preserve all "group-theoretic" properties, which includes the order of an element $\,g,\,$ since this equals the order (cardinality) of the cyclic group generated by $\,g.\,$ But an isomorphic image of a group has the same order (cardinality).

Yours is the special case of a *conjugation* isomorphism $\ g\mapsto bgb^{-1},\, $ with inverse $\ g\mapsto b^{-1}gb.$

Answer (score 7):

Proof 1: $\phi(x)=bxb^{-1}$ (for a fixed $b$) is a group automorphism. So, order of $a$= order of $bab^{-1}$.

Proof 2: $(bab^{-1})^n=ba^nb^{-1}$ for all natural number $n$. This shows the above result.