# Prove that any conjugate of $a$ has the same order as $a$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to prove that any conjugate of $a$ has the same order as $a$.

Let $G$ be a group and let $a \in G$.  An element $b \in G$ is called a conjugate of $a$ if $b=xax^{-1}$.

My professor gave us a hint.  Prove $a^k=e$ iff $b^k=e$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ implies $o(a) = o(b)$.

My first move is to $b^k = (xax^{-1})^k = (x^{-1})^ka^kx^k = (x^{-1})^kex^k = (x^{-1})^kx^k=x^{-k+k}=x^0$

I am not sure that I am doing this correctly?  I am trying to get $b^k=e$.  However when I raise $(xax^{-1})^k$, I am not sure if I what I have done is correct?

I am kind of confused here.

Comment: See also: [Order of conjugate of an element given the order of this element](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633757/order-of-conjugate-of-an-element-given-the-order-of-this-element)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The step $(xax^{-1})^k=x^ka^kx^{-k}$ is wrong. What you should have is
$$(xax^{-1})^k=xax^{-1}xax^{-1}\cdots xax^{-1}=xaea\cdots ax^{-1} = xa^kx^{-1}.$$

Comment: Well that makes a lot more sense now!  I think I can finish this problem now.