# If matrix $A=P^{-1}BP$ ($A$ is similar to $B$), prove that $|A^k|=|B^k|$.

Tags: matrices

> If $A=P^{-1}BP$, prove $|A^k|=|B^k|$.

Please give me the idea!

Comment: What's $\lvert X\rvert$?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path: I'm guessing it's the order, i.e., the smallest positive $n$ such that $X^n$ is the identity matrix (and $\infty$ if no such $n$ exists).

Comment: @AryamanMaithani I would have guessed otherwise, and I still do.

Comment: If you do mean order, then look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734317/prove-that-any-conjugate-of-a-has-the-same-order-as-a

Comment: Oh wait, I just realised that it would make more sense for it to be interpreted as the determinant. I just haven't seen that notation in a long time.

Comment: I guess you mean that |A| denotes the determinant of A.  If so, you can raise both LS and RS to the power k, then grouping $P^{-1}P $as $I $yields $A^k=P^{-1}B^kP $ and then taking determinant on both sides gives the result.Wish it helps. :| D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By induction it easy to prove that $A^k=P^{-1}B^kP$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. So $|A^k|=|P^{-1}||B^k||P|$. But since $|P^{-1}|=|P|^{-1}$,
$$|A^k|=|B^k|$$
for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

> If $B$ is invertible then it can be shown that $|A^k|=|B^k|$ for every
> $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your matrices are square matrices, and $|A|$ is the [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) of the matrix $A$, you can write:

$$|A^k| = |A|^k = |P^{-1} B P|^k = (|P|^{-1} |B| |P|)^k,$$

since the determinant of a product of matrices is the product of their determinants. (Which you can prove using the explicit definition of the determinant.)
The result then follows from commutativity of $\mathbb R$.