# $G$, group. $a,b\in G$. Show that $|a|=|a^{-1}|; |ab|=|ba|$, and $|a|=|cac^{-1}|, \forall c\in G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Isn't it obvious for $|a|=|a^{-1}|$, since $\langle a\rangle = \langle a^{-1} \rangle$?

For $|ab|=|ba|$, I think we should go like this: $e=(ab)^n\Rightarrow e=(ab)(ab)^{n-1}\Rightarrow (ab)^{-1}=(ab)^{n-1}\Rightarrow b^{-1}a^{-1}=(ab)^{n-1}\Rightarrow a^{-1}=b(ab)^{n-1}$ But I get stuck here, since I don't know whether to get from here to $e=(ba)^n$.

For $|a|=|cac^{-1}|$, do I have to show that $\langle a\rangle = \langle cac^{-1}\rangle$?

Comment: The first should work. For the second, it can be helpful to consider $ b (ab)^na =(ba)^{n+1}$. For the third, you should show $(cac^{-1})^n=ca^nc^{-1}$

Comment: All three statements are (multiple) duplicates on math.SE.

Comment: First question: [An element of a group has the same order as its inverse](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1008610/an-element-of-a-group-has-the-same-order-as-its-inverse)

Comment: Second question: [Is it true that the order of ab is always equal to the order of ba?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238212/is-it-true-that-the-order-of-ab-is-always-equal-to-the-order-of-ba)

Comment: The third one: [Order of conjugate of an element given the order of this element](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633757/order-of-conjugate-of-an-element-given-the-order-of-this-element) and [Prove that any conjugate of $a$ has the same order as $a$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734317/prove-that-any-conjugate-of-a-has-the-same-order-as-a)

Comment: Maybe it is worth mentioning that you can get the third one from the second one and also second one from the third one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the answers and comments helped me, but here is my own answer which brings a complete solution in one place.

First of all, we need to recall the following theorem.

> Theorem 3.4.iii (XXIX.iii), Algebra (Hungerford)
>
> Let $G$ be a group and $a\in G$. If $a$ has finite order $m>0$, then
>   $m$ is the least positive integer that $a^m=e$.

Now $|a|=|a^{-1}|$, because

$|a|=n\Rightarrow a^n=e\Rightarrow (a^n)^{-1}=e^{-1}\Rightarrow (a^{-1})^n = e\Rightarrow |a^{-1}|=n\Rightarrow |a|=|a^{-1}|.$

And I also think I can say this statement is true because $\langle a\rangle = \langle a^{-1} \rangle$.

$|ab|=|ba|$ because

$(ab)^n=e\Rightarrow (ab)(ab)^n(ab)=(ab)(ab)=a(ba)b\Rightarrow (ab)^n(ab)^{n^2}(ab)^n=a^n(ba)^nb^n\Rightarrow e=a^n(ba)^nb^n\Rightarrow (ab)^{-n}=(ba)^n\Rightarrow ((ab)^n)^{-1}=(ba)^n\Rightarrow e=(ba)^n$

Hence, $|ab|=|ba|$.

And finally, $|a|=|cac^{-1}|$, because from the statement we proved right above, we know that $|xy|=|yx|, \forall x,y\in G$. Let $x=c$ and $y=ac^{-1}$, so we've got $|yx|=|ac^{-1}c|=|a|$ and $|xy|=|cac^{-1}|$, yielding $|a|=|cac^{-1}|$.

hacked :)

Answer (score 3):

For the second one:

Notice that as $(ab)^n=1$. Then we have $(ab)^{n-1}=(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$.

Now consider $(ba)^n$:
$$(ba)^n=b(ab)^{n-1}a=bb^{-1}a^{-1}a=e.$$

Hence $|ba| \Big\lvert |ab|$.

Now think, from the last computations, why one must have equality.

Comment: Oh, you posted your own answer while I was writing.

Comment: Thanks, but if you've written the complete answer, post it and I'll choose your answer as the accepted one rather than mine. :)

Answer (score 2):

For 1) Let $|a|=n$ , i.e. $a^n=e$

Now take inverse both side $(a^n)^{-1}=e^{-1}$ which gives $(a^{-1})^n=e$

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question correctly, and I am not misinterpreting your notation. The last part utilizes the second part. If for all $a_1,a_2 \in G$ we have
$$ |a_1a_2| = |a_2a_1|$$
Then let $a \in G$ and $c \in G$ be arbitrary, and  $a_1 = c$ and $a_2 = ac^{-1}$. Now use the second property displayed above.

Comment: Simple and smart, good one :)