# In any group where $ab=b^4a$ and $b^6=e$ we have $b^3=e$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group and $a,b$ are in $G$ and we have  $ab=b^4a$ and $b^6=e$ where $e$ is the identity, then prove $b^3=e$.

I have played around with this for an hour or so by now, but the solution just keeps escaping me.

Comment: I added a more *conceptual* answer (that makes the proof obvious from well-know facts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $aba^{-1} = b^4$. Now

$$a b^3 a^{-1} = (aba^{-1})^3 = b^{12} = e$$

Hence $b^3 = a^{-1} e a = e$.

Comment: Implicitly this is exploiting the fact that conjugation is a group isomorphism so preserves order, so then we can  use well-known facts relating the order of $\,b^4\,$ to the order of $\,b,\,$ e.g. see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Given that $ab=b^4a$, it follows that
$$\begin{align}
ab^3&=(ab)b^2\\
&=(b^4a)b^2\\
&=b^4(ab)b\\
&=b^4(b^4a)b\\
&=b^8(ab)\\
&=b^{12}a\\
&=ea\\
&=a.
\end{align}$$

Comment: This is so slick and instructive; the underlying theme is to notice that substitution of $b^4 a$ for $ab$ increases the power of $b$, and when that power reaches a large enough value, we can reduce it via $b^6 = e$.

Comment: @heropup More *instructive* is to exploit the fact that conjugation is a group isomorphism so preserves order, then use well-know facts relating the order of $\,b^4\,$ to the order of $\,b,\,$ e.g. see my answer.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

*Conceptually*, the [Key Idea](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/622394/242) is that conjugation $\,b\mapsto aba^{-1}$ is a group isomorphism so preserves group theory properties such as $\,o(b) := $ order of $b= |\langle b\rangle|.\,$ This view makes the proof obvious. OP is the special case below: $\,n,k = 6,4,\,$ so the gcd $(n,k) = (6,4)=2,\,$ so $\,j = 6/2 = 3$

**Theorem** $\ \ \ \color{#0a0}{ab = b^{\large k}a},\ b^{\large n} = 1\,\Rightarrow\, b^{\large j} = 1,\,$ for $\ j = n/(n,k)$

**Proof** $ $ Key Idea $\,\Rightarrow\, o(b) = o(\color{#0a0}{aba^{-1}}) = o(\color{#0a0}{b^k})\mid j\,$ via [standard $\color{#90f}{\rm Lemma}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1906763/242) relating $\,o(b^k)$ to $\,o(b)$.

Comment: Bill, fully agree, +1-ed you since this conceptual proof learns more.

Comment: @Nicky Thanks, I abstracted out the Lemma since it likely obscured the simplicity of the one-line proof.

Answer (score 1):

We have $aba^{-1}=b^4$ and hence using $b^6=e$,
$$
b^4=b^{16}=(aba^{-1})^4=ab^4a^{-1}
$$
So $ab^4a^{-1}=aba^{-1}$, hence $b^3=e$.

Comment: I think it is shorter to do $b=a^{-1}b^4a$ thus $b^3=a^{-1}b^{12}a=a^{-1}ea=e$.